DMARC fail while SPF pass and DKIM pass
We have our own mail server (example.com). When sending emails through our code which resides on another server to our mail server, we receive SPF and DKIM pass but DMARC fails.
mail header:
From:   <noreply@example.com>
SPF:    PASS with <IP>
DKIM:   'PASS' with domain example.com
DMARC:  'PASS'

Return-Path: <noreply@example.com>
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=example.com;
Authentication-Results: OpenDMARC; dmarc=fail (p=quarantine dis=quarantine) header.from=example.com
Authentication-Results: OpenDMARC; spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=noreply@example.com ```

